# InlineKeyboardMarkup pyTelegramApiBot кнопки

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать архитектуру кнопок.Например мне нужно чтобы выводилось все эти кнопки в одном сообщении и чтобы они были разной `row_width` 

Как сделать чтобы кнопки вот так:
[--------Кнопка------]
[--------Кнопка------]
[--------Кнопка------]
[--------Кнопка------]
[--------Кнопка------]
[  Кнопка ][ Кнопка  ]

```
    courses = [['0'],['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6'],['7'],['8'],['9'],['10'],['11'],['12'],['13'],['14'],['15'],]
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    course = courses[0:5]
    for i in course:
        BCourse= types.InlineKeyboardButton(str(i),callback_data=str(i))
        markup.add(BCourse)
    markups = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    Bback= types.InlineKeyboardButton('<',callback_data='<')
    Bnext= types.InlineKeyboardButton('>',callback_data='>')
    markups.add(Bback,Bnext)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Выберите Курс:",
                    reply_markup=markup)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,text='sd',
                        reply_markup=markups)
```

Пример из другого телеграмм бота
[image: Пример картинки]

Answer (score 2):

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
course = courses[0:5]
Bback = types.InlineKeyboardButton('<', callback_data='<')
Bnext = types.InlineKeyboardButton('>', callback_data='>')
for i in course:
    BCourse = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str(i), callback_data=str(i))
    markup.add(BCourse)
markup.add(Bback, Bnext)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]